# Minor bug in vote to close "no more votes today" pop-up?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, user-interface, close-reasons

Perhaps this has recently changed intentionally, but I've just noticed that the full close form is appearing even when I'm not yet able to vote. (Until recently I was just getting the "Sorry you can't vote for another X hours" mini pop-up.)

[image]

It's only a *very* minor issue (more of a UI irregularity), as I can't actually vote to close, but I'm pretty sure this wasn't like this until recently. (Potentially related to the "time to permitted vote" being less than an hour, but that's pure speculation.)

Of course, I should probably be all tucked up in bed at this time here in GMT land, but... :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is by design. We want to present the options at all times.

Comment: It's by design that they *appear*, but why can we actually *select* them? I shouldn't be able to click "Vote to Close" if I have no votes left, it should behave like it does when I've *already* voted (i.e., no radio buttons).